# Chef::Exceptions::InvalidRemoteFileURI - nil is not a valid `source` parameter for remote_file. `source` must be an absolute URI or an array of URIs

Tags: chef-infra, artifactory, chef-recipe

I am trying to download artifacts from artiifactory using remote_file. where I am having the url in attributes.I am facing the below error.

```rb
remote_file "#{Chef::Config['file_cache_path']}/test.zip" do
  source node['build']['url']
  checksum node['build']['checksum']
end
```

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: you question is unclear. please rephrase it and state what is the problem (is it authentication?)

Answer (score 0):

Your `source` parameter of `remote_file` resource doesn't have a valid value. The attribute `node['build']['url']` , you are trying to access is not properly set. Make sure it is set to an absolute URI or an array of URIs as mentioned in exception. For testing, you can can open chef shell by running `chef-shell -z` command and can print the value of `node['build']['url']`